# Zero time spent in initial state in multi-state model?

Tags: survival, competing-risks, multi-state

I'm modelling an illness-death multi-state model (see image, taken from the {survival} vignette, https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/compete.pdf), and have a basic question: in my data, some individuals start in the 'Health' state, whilst some start in the 'Illness' state. I believe the initial state has to be the same for everyone, so should I implement those starting in 'Illness' as having spent zero time in the initial state, 'Health', does this violate model assumptions?

[image: Illness-death model diagram]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although simple examples might have all individuals starting in the same state, that's not a requirement of multi-state models. The models are for each of the allowed transitions, so software should allow for specification of initial states for all individuals.

In the R `survival` package, you can specify an `istate` argument to `coxph()` that points to "the current state at the start each interval," according to the software help page. The [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/compete.pdf) you cite mentions that in Section 2.2, on page 8.

I suspect that other multi-state modeling software provides the same possibility.